# Executing a command via PHP

Tags: audio, web, omxplayer

I currently have an Apache web server running on my Pi that has this as the `index.php` file:

```php5
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['play'])) {
        exec('sudo omxplayer yes.m4a');
    }
?>
```

However, my code doesn't work! When I visit the page, nothing happens on my Pi. I know that exec does work, because when I use another command such as `li`, I get an output. Is there any error(s) in my code?

Whenever someone visits the webpage with the url, say, `10.0.1.23/?play=1`, I want the Pi to run my audio file. I have been looking for what feels like forever, but to no avail.

If this is not possible for any reason (although I am almost sure it is), then what would be the easiest way to do this? I need to have my audio file get executed from another computer with minimal delay, as this is for my lab where, as long as it's consistent, a 1/4 of a second delay would be fine.

Edit: I have tried running the web server on my mac with the same code, only instead of `sudo omxplayer yes.m4a` I used `say test` and it seemed to have worked fine. Still not sure why my Pi isn't running my audio.

Comment: Does sound work correctly otherwise (without PHP)?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yes. Not sure why it's not working when running it via PHP.

Comment: Where are you expecting the sound to play on the computer with the webpage or back to the client over the web?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I am expecting the sound to play on my Pi.

Comment: I think the problem is the sudo. First the sudo is going to try and run as the webserver user which may not be sudo enabled. running exec can be a security problem and this adds to that insecurity. One way around this may be to create a bash script to run the audio file and call that instead of the omxplayer command. The bash script will need to have the owner/group permissions set so the webserver user can call it. Another alternative is to add an entry to the sudoers file (make sure to edit this file with sudo visudo this checks for syntax errors which could stop your system from booting).

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs?  /var/log/apache2/error.log (on my Pi). It's highly unlikely the Apache user (www-data?) is allowed to sudo.  Get rid of the sudo and grant the Apache user access to the audio devices.

Comment: @SteveRobillard What I understand from this is that I should create a bash script with `omxplayer yes.m4a` and execute it with PHP using `exec('/home/pi/code/play.sh');`?

Comment: Yeah, I would give that a try you may still have to add a sudoer rule to avoid using sudo in the bash file. You may want to google "php exec sudo" for more details. If I am correct the problem is that the user that is executing the exec call (Pi or www-data) does not have permission to run the sudo command.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thanks! It works great! My only last question is how can I shorten the delay? Currently there is something like a 0.75 second delay, but in our experiment every second is crucial. It might just be my home bandwidth right now (~ 1mb download) but it would surprise me if that was the issue.

Comment: How big is the audio file? Is it as slow on each invocation or is it slower on the first call and faster on subsequent calls? Where is the file located: on the SD card or downloaded from the web? Have you considered ditching the sound for a visual indicator or a simple web based hit counter(which may be faster)? You should answer your own question with what worked and accept it as answer. If the performance is still a problem I would suggest opening a new question to address the performance.

Comment: @SteveRobillard The sound file is necessary. It is located on the drive and it isn't very big, about 40kb.

Comment: Have you considered using a strictly audio player, which would likely be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to specify the full path to the executable and/or data files:

```
exec('/usr/bin/sudo /check/the/path/omxplayer /your/home/directory/or/whatever/yes.m4a');
```

you may find the path to `omxplayer` using command `which omxplayer` and path to your data file using your linux command line experience.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried using `exec('/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/omxplayer /var/www/yes.m4a');` and it still doesn't work in PHP. However, it does work in command line, so could this have anything to do with where the audio gets output from when being run from PHP? Sort of a long shot, but I'm very new to Raspberry Pi programming. I also now know that `exec` its self does work, because I tried making the page run `mkdir` and it successfully created the directory.

Comment: @AndrewDassonville when you run `sudo` you might want to provide your password in some form, use `man sudo` to seek for your options. and I hope your web server runs under your name, because for user `www` or `www-data` there might be no access to `sudo` or the password is totally different.